# Matrix linear indexing

Tags: matrix, indexing, traversal

I need to traverse a rectangular grid in **continuous manner**. Here is an example of what I want, the number means sequence:

```
   + x
   y 0  1  2
     5  4  3
     6  7  8
```

At each step I know the index in matrix. Is there any way to calculate the coordinates? The inverse mapping for `[x + y * width]` doesn't help, beacuse it creates "steps" or "jumps". Is there any solution?

Here is explanation for "steps" mentioned above:

```
  + x
   y 0  1  2
     3  4  5 //at this moment the X coordinate changes by 3, thus create step
     6  7  8
```

Comment: What do you mean by steps? Can you give an example of each the expected and wrong behavior?

Comment: What order is the matrix stored in-column major or row major? You seems to be indicating it is in row major order, but are using a column major indexing scheme....

Comment: you may also be interested in space filling curves http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve as used in this famous cartoon http://xkcd.com/195/ (see explanation under picture)

Comment: @talonmies sorry I don't know what you mean, but it is possible that I mixed the indexing. At the outcome the majority doesn't matter

Comment: @andrew cooke   wow, that's really helpfull, this will create nice effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = index / width
if( y % 2 == 0 )
   x = index % width
else
   x = width - index % width - 1
```

I think that should do it.  It's a single modification of the standard way of calculating with "steps" as you call them.  You are only changing the way the calculation is done based upon the row.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted, plus it's simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

so you need to first increase the "x" component and then decrease right - so that you get a kind of snake-behavior? You will need an if statement (or some kind of modulo - magic). Let my try the magic:

```
y := floor(i/columnCount)
x = (y mod 2)*(i - y*columCount) + ((y+1) mod 2)*((columnCount -1) - (i - y*columnCount))
```